# Comparing Real Numbers in an Array

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have an array called Marks, that contains 5 elements. I want to loop through the array, and get the highest item in the Marks array. When I run the below code I get 23.45

```
var
 Marks: array[0..4] of real = (42.4,65.34,24.12,23.45,43.24);
 iHighest : real;
 iInt : integer;
begin
 iHighest := Marks[0];
 for iInt:= 0 to 4 do
  begin
   if (iHighest >= Marks[iInt]) then
    iHighest := Marks[iInt];
  end;
end;
ShowMessage('Highest Mark: ' + FloatToStr(iHighest)); // Returns 23.45
```

But when I change the if statement to `if (Marks[iInt] >= iHighest)` the showmessage returns the correct answer of 65.34. Please can you let me know what is the difference.

Comment: Debugging through your code can give you the answer to your question, as you step through your code you will be able to see what happens on each loop iteration.

Comment: Imagine that you want to find the tallest from some boys. You mark the first one's height at the wall, then check others. You will update that mark (`iHighest`) only when current boy `Marks[iInt]`is taller.

Comment: if you write your new if statement in the same operand order `if ( iHighest <= Marks[iInt] ) then` then you will recognize : you just inverted the condition. if you negate the condition, you will get the item on the other end of the sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the *highest* number. For that, your condition is wrong. Your code finds the *lowest* number.

Example of what happens in your code: 
At some point in time, `iHighest` is `42.4`; `iInt` is `2`, so `Marks[iInt]` is `24.12`. **Then `iHighest >= 24.12`, so it becomes `24.12`!** In others words, the *new* value of `iHighest` is *lower* than the initial value.

But, if you want to find the *highest* number, then only if the *currently investigated number* `(Marks[iInt]`) is *higher* than the current `iHighest`, you update `iHighest`.

And since you initialize `iHighest` with the first element (index 0) anyway, you only have to check the *others*:

```
for iInt := 1 to 4 do            // not: 0 to 4
  if Marks[iInt] > iHighest then // not the other way around
    iHighest := Marks[iInt];
```

Note that there is no need to check with `>=` either. You only update `iHighest` if the current value is *higher*, not if it is *equal*.

---

*The best way to find out such errors by yourself is by* debugging. ***The Delphi debugger is very easy to use*** and can show you step by step, *line by line*, how values change. *If you had used the debugger, you would have seen how, in your code* `iHighest` *would take on a lower value, not a higher one, on each update.*

*Just read the online help on using the debugger. It is much easier than you think.*

Answer (score 2):

`iHighest` is for marking greatest number. You have to change it if it is smaller than `Marks[iInt]`, so true condition will be `iHighest < Marks[iInt]` or `Marks[iInt] > iHighest`

Hope you got it.